# How to post "application/octet-stream" content type to RestAPI using RestAssured

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I'm trying to post "application/octet-stream" content type to RestAPI using RestAssured. But it's getting failed and throwing error like:
Don't know how to encode the ××××× as a byte stream. I have tried to use encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs() method but this meyhod is not available for RestAssured. Please suggest if there is any other way around to resolve this.

Comment: Can you please add some more details? Or post your code here?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm facing the same problem now.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and it turned out to be not a multipart upload but through the body.
Please do not mention the header explicitly as `application/octet-stream`.
I was able to solve it and got it working successfully with simple code ,

```
given(). header("Content-Type","text/csv"). headers("Authorization","bla- 
blah","Header 2","blahblah").
body(new File("your-file-[ath")). when(). post("/post-url");
```